# Add transition to hover after pseudo

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add a cool little opacity transition for my extension. I've looked up many ways to go about this, and nothing has seemed to work so far. Is this even possible? I have the latest version of Chrome.

[A preview of it not working](https://static.is-a-virg.in/5xxL_w727)

`CSS:`

```css
.container .primary:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 6s ease-out;
}

.container .primary:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  content: "Go through a list of friends to remove";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you even use pseudo-elements? Because screen readers can't see them. You got enough space to just use divs. Also, pseudo-elements should have two colons. Ex. `::after`

Comment: @RickardElimää I tried using a div, but It messed up my buttons positioning, so I just relied on pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to reproduce from your code but there's a few main problems:

- Your pseudo element has `top:100%` so it's probably hanging off the bottom of the screen somewhere. You can use `position:relative` on the container to prevent this.
- It's a bad idea to put text into pseudo elements. As another commenter pointed out, they can't be picked up by screen readers. [Here's an in-depth article on the w3 website about this](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F87.html).
- You absolutely do not want to transition something for 6 seconds! Try to stick to half a second maximum or your UI will feel slow. [Here's a great writeup on the subject.](https://uxdesign.cc/the-ultimate-guide-to-proper-use-of-animation-in-ux-10bd98614fa9)

And finally, a full snippet combining the above suggestions. This is not perfect by any means, but it should be enough to get you started:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding:10px;
  font-family:'Arial';
  border:1px solid black;
}

.container .tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  padding:10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.container .primary:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="primary">div
  <div class="tooltip">"Go through a list of friends to remove"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```